# Integrating mod_auth_openidc with a login form

Tags: openid-connect, mod-auth-openidc

I have several web sites running under Apache/CGI that need to authenticate users. The present mechanism is long past end of life, so I am looking to move to OpenID Connect. To make life easier, I want to use mod_auth_openidc rather than code something from scratch.

My organization supports OIDC directly. The tricky part is that we need to present the login form ourselves. So I have a small script that sends a login form, and an authentication handler that grabs the credentials and uses the REST service to authenticate them.

If I understand correctly, mod_auth_openidc associates its own session cookie with the OIDC token id/authorization code/access token, so that the user agent only ever has to know about the mod_auth_openidc_cookie.

Mod_auth_openidc doesn't seem to need more than minimal configuration in my situation. I am able to authenticate user credentials and get the token id/authorization code/access token from the OIDC privider service trivially. What I'm not clear on is how to send the user agent a response that gets them into the site if the credentials they present are good.

I have tried a 302 into the landing page of my application, sending just the token id in the iPlanet, but that doesn't work, because mod_auth_openidc doesn't see the the token id.

Comment: "My organization supports OIDC directly. The tricky part is that we need to present the login form ourselves. " seems contradictory: the point of using OpenID Connect is to relay the authentication to a central service

Comment: We don't want to:
1) expose our OIDC provider servers that would normally accept the username/password to direct access from the Internet at large.
2) Use other OIDC providers.

My job is to gather the username/password credentials from external users, get them authenticated, and then pass things on to mod_auth_oidc.

I do have mod_auth_openidc pretty much working using Kerberos with our OIDC provider servers for internal users on Chrome, Edge and FF in our development environment, except that an HTML redirect missing the port number gets inserted to the HTML of our landing page.